# Try Catch doesnt try the second condition

Tags: c#, winforms

i have 2 condition inside try which is ||. The first condition will not try to catch. But the second one, it does.

```
    private void ButtonExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (fbd[0].SelectedPath != null || fbd[1].SelectedPath != null)
            {
                SearchingPhoto();
            }
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException)
        { return; }
    }
```

Method in try will run if and only if fbd[0].SelectedPath is not equal to null.

case 1: `if(fbd[0].SelectedPath != null || fbd[1].SelectedPath != null)`OK

case 2: `if(fbd[0].SelectedPath == null || fbd[1].SelectedPath != null)`not OK

case 3: `if(fbd[0].SelectedPath != null || fbd[1].SelectedPath == null)`OK

case 4: `if(fbd[0].SelectedPath == null || fbd[1].SelectedPath == null)`not OK

//i want to run a method inside case 2:

Comment: When `fbd[0].SelectedPath == null` did you check if `fbd[0]` and `fbd` are `null`? I'm betting one of them is and the method goes to the `catch` block.

Comment: i need to run a method if one of them is not null

Comment: Why do you think that `fbd[1].SelectedPath` is not `null`? have you debugged it? Does it throw an exception? does it just not enter inside the `if` block?

Comment: Also, adding to @Guy comment, try it with: `fbd[0]?.SelectedPath != null || fbd[1]?.SelectedPath != null`

Comment: yes i debugged it, second condition seems doesnt check whatever condition there is. only fbd[0].SelectedPath check with try statement. so second condition in this try statement doesnt matter or useless.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten, surprisingly adding ? is the right answer in my case. It seems strange.

Comment: It's not strange - it's beacuse `fbd[0]` itself is `null`

Comment: I think there is no instance of fbd . this can throw exception. try checking if that is present in scope

Comment: try declaring fbd globally as field of class

Comment: fbd are already global. just adding "?", there's no need of exception. i'll just use `if(fbd[0]?.SelectedPath != null || fbd[1]?.SelectedPath != null)` and everything is OK.

Answer (score 6):

You are not getting a *NullReferenceException*, that's why the catch does not "catch".

You will receive null reference exception if you are using a property of that instance and it is null for example:

```
fbd[0].SelectedPath.SomeProp //Will cause exception if fbd[0].SelectedPath is null
```

If you want to find out if one of them is null why not simply:

```
fbd[0].SelectedPath == null || fbd[1].SelectedPath == null
```

Of course fbd[i] can also be null and you will get exception if you are trying to read the property SelectedPath from it.

Added:

Always good practice is to check if the instance you are using is not null if there is a chance it will be.

```
if (fbd[0]!=null && fbd[0].SelectedPath != null || 
    fbd[1]!=null && fbd[1].SelectedPath != null) 
    {
      //Safe to use
    }
```

Comment: i dont want to receive an exception if one of them is not null.

Comment: Always good practice is to check if the instance you are using is not null if there is a chance it will be. @Vincent

Answer (score 1):

here is my final method

```
    private void ButtonExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fbd[0]?.SelectedPath != null || fbd[1]?.SelectedPath != null)
        {
            SearchingPhoto();
        }    
    }
```